# Function to find longest common subsequences of a list of lists?

Tags: list, function, haskell

How can I find the longest subsequences that two lists have in common? For example:

```
["abcdefg", "abc__fg", "ab____g"]
```

It should return:

```
["ab", "g"]
```

Is there an existing function that does this? How would you compose one from existing ones?

Comment: Question in body is quite different from that in the title.

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear. I'm not looking for anything subjective. I want to know how to solve this problem. I'm assuming there's some useful functions that can accomplish this. Thanks!

Comment: Are you really looking for _maximal_ common subsequences?

Comment: @ErikR I'm not sure. The use case is removing the common portions of a list of chapter titles from web books. The pages will have the book title in each chapter, I want to extract the unique part from a list of strings.

Comment: Will the common parts always be at the beginning and end? For instance, `ab` is the longest common prefix and `g` is the longest common suffix. That would really simplify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [Data.List.CommonSubstring](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/string-similarity-0.1.0.0/docs/Data-List-CommonSubstring.html)

```
$ ghci
λ: :m +Data.List.CommonSubstring
λ: longestSubstring "abcdefg" "abc__fg"
"abc"
```

It's unclear what exactly you want (longest subsequence or all possible subsequences), so feel free to use [Data.SuffixTree](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/suffixtree-0.2.2.1/docs/Data-SuffixTree.html) directly to implement required logic.